# Why does the static dot graph definition not working in newer versions of Jaseci?

Tags: jaseci

I'm using `jaseci - 1.3.5.13` version. I'm trying to execute following code snippet to define a static graph;

```
graph test_graph {
    has anchor graph_root;
    graph G {
        graph_root [node=test_node, name=root]
        node_1 [node=test_node, name=node_1]
        node_2 [node=test_node, name=node_2]
        graph_root -> node_1 [edge=special]
        graph_root -> node_2
        }
    }
```

I got encountered syntax error in all of these code lines. Is there anything missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it was deprecated in newer versions of Jaseci, spawn style graphs are now the official way to specify graphs. The dot-style graph added much more complexity to the Jac language grammar and interpreter. A better approach would be to build a dot standard library for loading dot files and parsing them into Jaseci graphs. Perhaps this dot library will be built one day, and feel free to contribute it to the open source project if you'd like!!